# Probabilities in markov graphs

Tags: probability, markov-process, graph-theory

I have a first order markov graph which looks like

[image: this]

Now I was told if we make B an **absorbing state(NULL)** the graph simplifies to

[image: this]

I was also told that the conversion probability is 1 in the first graph and .5 in the second graph.

I have two doubts regarding this
1. It is not clear to me how conversion probability is 1 for the first graph and .5 for the second graph 
2.It is not clear to me if the first and the second graph are the same and that redistributing the probability of A falling upon itself will not change the nature of the graph

Any help in understanding this will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first graph, it is "probabilistically certain" that we will sooner or later end up in the node $\mathrm{CONVERSION}$, so the "conversion probability" is 1. In the second graph, on the other hand, once we move from $\mathrm{A}$ to $\mathrm{NULL}$, there is no coming back.

The second graph arises from the first one by "making B an absorbing state", and the probability of the transition $\mathrm{A} \rightarrow \mathrm{CONVERSION}$ in this new graph is $50 \%$, indeed, because it is equal to $a + b a + b^2 a + b^3 a + \dots$, which is equal to $a (1+b+b^2+\dots) = a \frac{1}{1-b} = 0.5 = 50 \%$, where $a := 37.5 \% = \frac{3}{8}$ and $b := 25 \% = \frac{1}{4}$. (The summand $b^n a$ (for $n \in \mathbb{N}$) here corresponds to the path $\mathrm{A} \rightarrow \mathrm{A} \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow \mathrm{A} \rightarrow \mathrm{CONVERSION}$, where we first move from $\mathrm{A}$ to $\mathrm{A}$ $n$ times and only then move to $\mathrm{CONVERSION}$.)

Comment: This was the explanation I was looking for.